# Interaction HTTP response not sending files in Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been making a Discord bot (on **discord.js v14**), and I've been trying to make a command that sends a video, but for some reason it refuses to send any kind of files, and I don't know why.

I've done so much research (in the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files), other questions, youtube videos), but none have solved my issue.

I tried what I assume the documentation was telling me to do:

```
return response.send({
   type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
   data: {
      files: [{filename: "./videos/video.mp4"}], // example path
      content: "Test"
   },
});
```

`response` comes from the `app.post/interactions` event. (`interactionCreate` event doesn't work for me).

```
app.post('/interactions', async function (request, response)
```

I expected it to post "Test" and the video below, but it *only* posted "Test". I have tried to figure this out for so long and nothing has worked. The file path is correct, I'm 100% certain (it's not giving me errors related to it), so I know it's not that.

One thing I found out is that if I make it like this where it says `attachments`, instead of just sending "Test", it will tell me that the interaction failed.

```
 return response.send({
     type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
     data: {
        content: "Test",
        attachments: ["./videos/video.mp4"] // example path
     },
 });
```

Comment: Try `files: ["./videos/video.mp4"]`.

Comment: I have tried that, and it hasn't worked

Comment: Do you have checked application.commands when you add your bot by link?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make use of **discord attachments**. This can be done by using the discord.js **AttachmentBuilder** class:

Bring it in from the library:

```js
const { AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
```

And create the attachment:

```js
const file = new AttachmentBuilder('./videos/video.mp4');
```

You can then include it in the message using the "files" option in the .reply() (or similar) method's options object, like so:

```js
interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed], files: [file] });
```

Reference: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#attaching-images

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. My bot doesn't use the interaction object, it uses an HTTP response to send text or embeds. I've tried to make it work with the interaction object system but that didn't work, so I just used what did work.

Comment: After a further look at your code, it looks like you're not using the Discord.JS library, but instead the discord APIs (Either the Gateway, using WebSockets, or just general HTTP requests). If you'd prefer to use a library to simplify things, check out the https://discordjs.guide - If you let me know if you're using the Gateway or standard HTTP, I can try and help look for answers through those!

Comment: Discord.js was one of the first libraries I imported for this bot. I looked at the guides and tried to set up an interactionCreate event, but it never received anything

Comment: It may be worth making a new question for the DiscordJS Problem. From research, I don't believe you can upload attachments without using the Gateway API, so you'll need to either use the gateway API directly or use a library instead.